# Change Bootstrap icon color

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I print this icon into a table using php code like this:

```
echo '<button Onclick="" style="border: none; background: none; color:green"><a title="Reenviar" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="material-icons">&#xE0BE;</i></a></button>';
```

And I'd ike to change the icon's color. I tried to add the color to the button style; however it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should add style to i tag

```
<i style = "color:blue;" class="material-icons">&#xE0BE;</i>
```

also, you can create a css class

```
.blue {
    color:blue
}
```

and then just add that class to a tag

```
<i class="material-icons blue">&#xE0BE;</i>
```

Comment: You can of course also make use of the text colour classes like `text-success`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the styling to the icon itself if you are using inline styling.

```
<i style="color: #ff0000" class="material-icons">&#xE0BE;</i>
```

Better yet you can use some some css to make this cleaner and more manageable and do something in css like this

```
.material-icons {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Checkout the css w3 schools code examples https://www.w3schools.com/css/